# Register task in windows task scheduler in java

Tags: java, windows, events, calendar

How can I register a task in windows task scheduler using java?

What I want is that my calendar java program will notify me if there is an event in that hour. I want to be notified even if my computer is in sleep mode.

Is it possible to register a task in the Windows task scheduler using java?
If it is possible, How?

I read some questions related to this in Stack Overflow and someone answered. 
His/her answer is that, register the task to windows task scheduler and it will tell motherboard to wake up when it needed to run the task.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has the commands `at` and `schtasks` which allow you to create and manage scheduled tasks from the command line. See this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738335%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for further documentation.

If you know how to run this commands for your needs you can invoke them from Java using [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).